# BC or CE (or something else) in a translation?

Tags: word-choice, translation

A direct translation of what I'm translating from Swedish is:

> Hippocrates lived several hundred years BC.

No matter how many times I look at it, it seems wrong. Is it?

I've also tested writing:

> Hippocrates lived several hundred years before the Common Era.

and

> Hippocrates lived several hundred years before Christ.

At this point everything looks suspicious to me. I looked at COCA to see how frequently Common Era is used, but I didn't find it helpful this time. Taking away the religious aspect would not be a bad thing.

What would you write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either "lived several hundred years BC" or "lived several hundred years before Christ" would be the 'traditional' way to write this (I've seen both ways used), but increasingly common now would be to write "lived several hundred years BCE" or "lived several hundred years before the Common Era" (again, I'm sure I've seen both of these used).

I think overall my preference would be to say "lived several hundred years BCE", especially if you prefer to take out the religious aspect.

Comment: Another way is to add 2016 and mark dates as "BP" (Before Present).

Comment: @JohnLawler I've read a (very) little about BP at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Before_Present and it appears to be used mainly by geologists. Using it could create confusion?